# "One of the bests" vs "One of the best"

Tags: grammar

What is correct between "bests" & "best", when used in the context as per title.
To clarify, there is no noun after this term.
i.e. it's not *"one of the best [XYZ]s"*.

Example:
I had been to that restaurant. It's indeed **one of the best/bests** (?)"

Comment: "It is one of the best" is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Best" is a **superlative adjective**, so it uses the -est suffix, which doesn't pluralize. For example, you would always say:

"Kate's a great racer. One of the fastest."

Though she's among a set of fastest racers, you would never say she's one of the "fastests." The same construction applies to "best." There's a sort of intuitive logic to this pattern -- the adjective itself denotes the highest degree of some quality, a singular position, that may then modify a plural if multiple entities hold that quality.

Answer (score 0):

["One of the bests"](http://www.onelook.com/?w=bests&ls=a) is an uncommon use of the word best, and generally considered incorrect. Stick with "one of the best." :)

[Wordreference forums,](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/one-of-the-best-or-bests.1757760/) , [quora.com,](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-one-of-the-best-or-one-of-the-bests) , [and Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081130073515AAmG6oC) are some examples of the general opinion. :)

Comment: If you're going to link to a readily-available reference for a  question showing no signs of research (which you shouldn't on ELU), at least give a specific reference with an example or apparent lack of availability of a usage.